# Javascript error notification on form not working

Tags: javascript, forms, client-side

**I'm working on a basic html form** ; the errors are showing quite well but they are not disappearing after the correct input is filled in. I have tried functions of removing the error but nothing is working. Various functions only remove the error on the first input which is the username.is there a way that I can remove the error immediately after the correct input is fed in.
however id like one to explain using an easy methodology. thanks!!

### THE HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Setting the pages character encoding -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
    <!-- The meta viewport will scale my content to any device width -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

     <!-- Link to my stylesheet -->
     <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">  -->
    <script async="false" src="script.js"></script> <!-- Link to the javascript file -->
    <style>
        .error {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>

    <title>CSC309 assignment 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<section class="page">
    
    <h1>can you validate me ?</h1>

    <form name="register-form" action="/" method="get" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return false">

        <p class="success register-success"></p>

        
        <label>Username: <span>Choose a username</span> </label>
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <p class="error username-error" id="username_notification"></p>

        

        <label>Password: <span>Please use a strong password</span> </label>
        <input type="text" name="password">
        <p class="error password-error" id="password1_notification"></p>

        <label>Confirm Password: <span>Please type again your password</span> </label>
        <input type="text" name="confirm">
        <p class="error confirm-password-error" id="password2_notification"></p>


        <label>Email: <span>Please enter an active email</span> </label>
        <input type="text" name="email">
        <p class="error email-error" id="email_notification"></p>

        <label for="phone">phone:<span>enter phone number </span></label>
        <input type="text" name="phone">
        <p class="error phone-error" id="phone_notification" ></p>

        <input type="submit" name="register-submition" value="register" id="register">

        <p class="error register-error"></p>
    </form>
</section>
<hr>

</body>
</html>
```

### JAVASCRIPT

```
document.forms["register-form"].onsubmit = function (event) {
  //    username validation
  if (this.username.value === "" || this.username.value == null) {
    document.querySelector(".username-error").innerHTML =
      "Please enter a username";
    document.querySelector(".username-error").style.display = "block";
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  } 
  
  
  if (this.username.value.length > 6) {
    document.querySelector(".username-error").innerHTML =
      "Username must be less than 6 characters";
    document.querySelector(".username-error").style.display = "block";
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  } 
  
  
  if (
    this.username.value.length <= 6 &&
    !this.username.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/)
  ) {
    document.querySelector(".username-error").innerHTML =
      "Username can only contain letters ,numbers and underscores";
    document.querySelector(".username-error").style.display = "block";
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  //   password1 validation
  
  
  
  if (this.password.value === "" || this.password.value == null) {
    document.querySelector(".password-error").innerHTML =
      "password cannot be empty";
    document.querySelector(".password-error").style.display = "block";
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  } 
  
  
  if (this.password.value.length < 8) {
    document.querySelector(".password-error").innerHTML =
      "password must be at least 8 characters";
    document.querySelector(".password-error").style.display = "block";
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  } 
  
  
  if (
    this.password.value.length >= 8 &&
    !this.password.value.match(
      /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*(_|[^\w])).+$/
    )
  ) {
    document.querySelector(".password-error").innerHTML =
      "password must contain at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number and one special character";
    document.querySelector(".password-error").style.display = "block";
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  //    confirm-password validation
  
  
  
  if (
    this.confirm.value === "" ||
    this.confirm.value == null
  ) {
    document.querySelector(".confirm-password-error").innerHTML =
      "confirm password cannot be empty";
    document.querySelector(".confirm-password-error").style.display = "block";
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  } 
  
  
  if (this.confirm.value !== this.password.value) {
    document.querySelector(".confirm-password-error").innerHTML =
      "passwords do not match";
    document.querySelector(".confirm-password-error").style.display = "block";
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }

  // email validation
  
  
  
  if (this.email.value === "" || this.email.value == null) {
    document.querySelector(".email-error").innerHTML = "email cannot be empty";
    document.querySelector(".email-error").style.display = "block";
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  } 
  
  
  if (this.email.value.length > 30) {
    document.querySelector(".email-error").innerHTML =
      "email must be less than 30 characters";
    document.querySelector(".email-error").style.display = "block";
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  } 
  
  
  if (
    this.email.value.length <= 30 &&
    !this.email.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/)
  ) {
    document.querySelector(".email-error").innerHTML =
      "email must be a valid email address";
    document.querySelector(".email-error").style.display = "block";
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  /*    if(this.email.value === ""){
       document.querySelector(".email-error").innerHTML = "Please enter a email";
       document.querySelector(".email-error").style.display = "block";
       event.preventDefault();
       return false;
    } */

  //    phone validation
  
  
  
  if (this.phone.value === "" || this.phone.value == null) {
    document.querySelector(".phone-error").innerHTML = "phone cannot be empty";
    document.querySelector(".phone-error").style.display = "block";
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  } 
  
  
  if (this.phone.value.length > 11) {
    document.querySelector(".phone-error").innerHTML =
      "phone number must be less than 11 characters";
    document.querySelector(".phone-error").style.display = "block";
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  } 
  
  
  if (
    this.phone.value.length <= 11 &&
    !this.phone.value.match(/^[0-9]+$/)
  ) {
    document.querySelector(".phone-error").innerHTML =
      "phone number can only contain numbers";
    document.querySelector(".phone-error").style.display = "block";
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  return Submit;

}
function removewarning(){
  document.getElementById("username_notification").addEventListener("input", function(){
    document.querySelector(".username-error").style.display = "none";
  });

}
```

---

Comment: You don't need to validate the form yourself by the way -- look into the `required` and `pattern` attributes on form controls.

Answer (score 0):

Just add else statement and define innerHTML = "" if the input is correct.

```
  if (
    this.password.value.length >= 8 &&
    !this.password.value.match(
      /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*(_|[^\w])).+$/
    )
  ) {
    document.querySelector(".password-error").innerHTML =
      "password must contain at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number and one special character";
    
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  } else {
    document.querySelector(".password-error").innerHTML = "";
  }
```